# Set scroller property for paper-header-panel (Polymer)

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

everyone!
I wanted to use paper-header-panel with mode waterfall and custom element '[iron-swipeable-pages](https://metanov.github.io/iron-swipeable-pages/components/iron-swipeable-pages/)'. My code looks somehow like this: (it is not the exact copy, just the structure)

```
<paper-drawer-panel id="drawer" force-narrow>
  <div drawer>
    <!-- Drawer panel -->
  </div>
  <div main> 
    <paper-header-panel id="paperHeaderPanel" mode="waterfall">
      <paper-toolbar id="appbar">
        <!-- Toolbar content -->
      </paper-toolbar>
      <iron-swipeable-pages
        padding="16"
        id="ironSwipeablePages"
        edge-swipe-sensitivity="30"
        selected="{{selected}}">
        <div id="overview">
          1
        </div>
        <div id="timetable">
          2
        </div>
        <div id="teachers">
          3
        </div>
        <div id="calendar">
          4
        </div>
      </iron-swipeable-pages>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </div>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

The `<div>` elements inside `<iron-swipeable-pages>` are scrollable but when I scroll them the waterfall effect on paper-header-panel isn't working.
I tried this:

```
this.$.paperHeaderPanel.scroller = this.$.overview;
```

In `ready` script of element because I saw that property isn't marked as read-only in [element reference](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-header-panel#property-scroller). However, it does not work. *Do you have any ideas how to make waterfall effect work?*